# Firebase Authentication behavior on client sign in error when merging anonymous account

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

We're using Firebase Authentication to anonymously authenticate users when they start their first session. Later on, they may choose to sign into a non-anonymous provider. We use the FirebaseUI library to assist with this. The FirebaseUI library has an auto-anonymous-upgrade feature ([docs](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/blob/master/Auth/README.md#handling-auto-upgrade-of-anonymous-users)) that we use to simplify this for us.

The docs outline several edge cases we have to handle, including the account merge scenario where the user signs into an existing account. When this happens we want to migrate the user data (in Firestore) associated with the anonymous account to the existing account, and finally sign into the existing account. This final step automatically and unavoidably discards the anonymous account on the client, such that we cannot revert to it.

Logically, this merge process isn't very complicated. The only tricky part is making this process as resilient/atomic as possible, such that a user cannot get stuck in some sort of "limbo" state.

There are two points of failure. The first is when we migrate the user data, and the second is when we sign into the existing account. Our idea to achieve atomicity is to start the migration before the user signs into the existing account, caching the data in a transaction that can be reverted, and then "commit" the migration after the sign in succeeds. This way, we should be able to abort the merge if the data migration fails, as well as if the sign in fails.

**My question is: if the `Auth.auth().signIn` returns an error, is the anonymous account guaranteed to not have been discarded?** In other words: if the sign in fails, can we continue to use the current anonymous user, or might the Auth SDK have discarded the anonymous user during its attempt to sign in?

Below is the FirebaseUI iOS/Swift delegate function skeleton, where I have indicated the migration events. We're also open to suggestions beyond our main question. We know we're not the first to implement this idea, but the docs/examples don't go this deep.

```
func authUI(_ authUI: FUIAuth, didSignInWith authDataResult: AuthDataResult?, error: Error?) {
    if let error = error as NSError?, error.code == FUIAuthErrorCode.mergeConflict.rawValue {
        // Merge conflict error, discard the anonymous user and login as the existing non-anonymous user.
        guard let credential = error.userInfo[FUIAuthCredentialKey] as? AuthCredential else {
            print("Received merge conflict error without auth credential!")
            return
        }

        // Start migration process

        Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (dataResult, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                print("Failed to re-login: \(error)")

                // Cancel migration process

                // WE NEED TO REVERT TO THE ANONYMOUS USER!

                return
            }

            // Finalize migration process
        }
    }
    else if let error = error {
        // Some non-merge conflict error happened.
        print("Failed to log in: \(error)")
        return
    }
    // Handle successful login
}
```